# API authentication through OAuth2 for "unregistered" users on a web/mobile app

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, hybrid-mobile-app, stormpath, stormpath-express

I'd like to implement authentication for unregistered users as well as registered users. As soon as user downloads the mobile app, I'd like them to start using certain parts of the app but still make requests with an access token. My plans was to register user with their UUID in the background and return an access token and store the key in keychain. I'm planning to use StormPath.

Is this plan a common practice for this situations?

How should I handle password field for anonymous users? How can I handle getting a new access token when refresh token is also expired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good enough plan for now, until Stormpath has native support for "anonymous" users.

I'd probably register:

- email: UUID@device.local. Store this in the keychain.
- password: (random string that you store in keychain) and use that to get new refresh tokens when needed. Or, make refresh tokens have very long lives =]

Comment: thank you! I'll try to join your webinar on 8th and maybe ask a couple of  more questions:)